# Верстка: почему не показывается картинка?

Tags: html, вёрстка

Есть [сайт](http://lydmila-mebel.ru/catalog/), там в шапке есть картинка, так вот она в фаерфоксе показывается, а в хроме не показывается. Вопрос почему?

Я понял, что это происходит из-за `.header_block img {display: block;}`, но я не понимаю, какое правило ему надо выставить.

Comment: @oldzas, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Все происходит потому, что контент в шапке отодвигает эту картинку за границы блока.
Вылечить это можно, добавив `position: absolute` к картинке. Но это не очень правильно.

По уму эту картинку нужно убрать в `background` к `header_block` и не умчаться.